# Count the number of unique words (case does not matter for this count)

Tags: c++, string, vector, word-count

Hey so I'm having trouble figuring out the code to count the number of unique words. My thought process in terms of psudeocode was first making a vector so something like `vector<string> unique_word_list;`Then I would get the program to read each line so I would have something like`while(getline(fin,line))`. The hard part for me is coming up with the code where I check the vector(array) to see if the string is already in there. If it's in there I just increase the word count(simple enough) but if its not in there then I just add a new element to the vector. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here. I feel like this is not hard but for some reason I can't think of the code for comparing the string with whats inside of the array and determining if its a unique word or not.

Comment: Hints: Use a `std::set`, read into it, then display its size.

Comment: Std::set would be better

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a `vector` - use a container that maintains uniqueness, like [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Just convert the string into lower case (using [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)) before you add it:

```
std::set<std::string> words;
std::string next;
while (file >> next) {
    std::transform(next.begin(), next.end(), next.begin(), std::tolower);
    words.insert(next);
}

std::cout << "We have " << words.size() << " unique words.\n"
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this that involves me taking in each line of the file though?

Comment: @Barry You may want to use `::tolower`, as otherwise some headers may include `<locale>`, which has the additional `std::tolower` [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower), and you'd get a compile-time error due to ambiguity in deducing the type of the functor. If you want `std::tolower` from `cctype`, then must explicitly tell the compiler the type so it's not forced to deduce it.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot help myself writing an answer that makes use of C++ beautiful library. I'd do it like this, with a `std::set`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifile("test.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> it{ifile};
    std::set<std::string> uniques;
    std::transform(it, {}, std::inserter(uniques, uniques.begin()), 
        [](std::string str) // make it lower case, so case doesn't matter anymore
        {
            std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
            return str; 
        });
    // display the unique elements
    for(auto&& elem: uniques)
        std::cout << elem << " ";

    // display the size:
    std::cout << std::endl << uniques.size();
}
```

You can also define a new string type in which you change the `char_traits` so the comparison becomes case-insensitive. This is the code you'd need (much more lengthy than before, but you may end up reusing it), the char_traits overload is copy/pasted from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct ci_char_traits : public std::char_traits<char> {
    static bool eq(char c1, char c2) { return toupper(c1) == toupper(c2); }
    static bool ne(char c1, char c2) { return toupper(c1) != toupper(c2); }
    static bool lt(char c1, char c2) { return toupper(c1) <  toupper(c2); }
    static int compare(const char* s1, const char* s2, size_t n) {
        while ( n-- != 0 ) {
            if ( toupper(*s1) < toupper(*s2) ) return -1;
            if ( toupper(*s1) > toupper(*s2) ) return 1;
            ++s1; ++s2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static const char* find(const char* s, int n, char a) {
        while ( n-- > 0 && toupper(*s) != toupper(a) ) {
            ++s;
        }
        return s;
    }
};

using ci_string = std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits>;

// need to overwrite the insertion and extraction operators, 
// otherwise cannot use them with our new type 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ci_string& str) {
    return os.write(str.data(), str.size());
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& os, ci_string& str) {
    std::string tmp;
    os >> tmp;
    str.assign(tmp.data(), tmp.size());
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifile("test.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<ci_string> it{ifile};
    std::set<ci_string> uniques(it, {}); // that's it

    // display the unique elements
    for (auto && elem : uniques)
        std::cout << elem << " ";

    // display the size:
    std::cout << std::endl << uniques.size();
}
```

Comment: @Barry, missed that :) I'd use my own case insensitive char trait here :)) Your answer though does it.

Comment: You could just std::transform tolower and use an insert iterator instead.

Comment: @Flexo thanks for the hint, modified it, just for fun with iterators and zips.

Comment: @Barry technically `std::basic_string`, as `std::string` is just the typedefed instantiation :) But yes, the traits design is beautiful, thumbs up for the people who design it.